# Reload function that make fancybox appear

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fancybox

i (with the help of user) already did one page that has a function to read a value on a txt file and if it's "1" a fancybox (version 2) with a iframe appear.

**Code ReadAndAppear.php**

```
<?php

$lines = file('alerta.txt');
$valrec= $lines[0];

echo $valrec;
if($valrec == 1){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $.fancybox({
        href: "alert.php",
        type: "iframe"
    });
}); //ready
</script>
<?php
}; // closes if
?>
```

So, to try that this function/page reload (*5-5 seconds*) to appear the fancybox if the *valrec* is *"1"* I create a new page, lets call it index.php

**index.php code**

head

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
function ()
{
$('#ReadAndAppear').load('ReadAndAppear.php').fadeIn("slow");
}, 50000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds

</script>
```

body

```
<div id="ReadAndAppear"></div>
```

unfortunately this code doesn't make the fancybox appear on the index.php when *valrec=1*. this algorithm only refresh and make appear images, *echos* etc, but not *fancybox*.

How can i make refresh and appear on the *index.php* or even better on *ReadAndAppear.php*

thanks

Comment: Either move/copy the script to the index.php or use `$.getScript()` after you have loaded the content. http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/ The JS from the remote page will not be loaded and run because of the way that the data is read into index.php

Comment: but if i copy to the index.php it works the same way as ReadAndAppear.php. I don't want that. i want that the functions reloads every five seconds.

Comment: Call `$.getScript()` in the callback of the `fadeIn()` and that should solve the problem. Ideally you should re-think your logic so that you would not have to do this.

Comment: I'm not sure if i understood what you sau becouse im a noob, sorry
I did 
$('#ReadAndAppear').load('ReadAndAppear.php').getScript();
and it doesnt work

Comment: I think you have a design problem here. I would move the code from ReadAndAppear.php into index.php, then just wrap the `$.fancybox({...})` script inside the `setInterval()` function .... that way you don't need to make a new http request for every refresh.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off storing the fancybox function in a separate JS file. Then you could call for it in the callback of the ReadAndAppear load function -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var auto_refresh = setInterval(
    function ()
    {
        $('#ReadAndAppear').load('ReadAndAppear.php').fadeIn("slow", function(){
            $.getScript('fancybox.js'); // gets and runs script
        });
    }, 50000); // refresh every 10000 milliseconds
</script>
```

In ReadAndAppear.php you can make changes to load the same script -

```
<?php

$lines = file('alerta.txt');
$valrec= $lines[0];

echo $valrec;
if($valrec == 1){
?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $.getScript('fancybox.js');
    }); //ready
    </script>
<?php
}; // closes if
?>
```

Now put the script in its own file **facybox.js**

```
$.fancybox({
    href: "alert.php",
    type: "iframe"
});
```

Honestly doing it this way has both good and bad points though. I think, as I said before in the comments, that I think your logic needs a little rethinking. I shouldn't have to use `$.getScript()` if my code is organized well and included in the project differently. It would be much easier to maintain.

Comment: thanks for the help, but didn't  work.
Do i have to import anything to the .js file?

Comment: You have to make sure that jQuery and the fancybox plugins files are included in each page.

Comment: i imported to ReadAndAppear.php and index.php and doesn't work

Comment: Without being able to see how the pages are setup and if there are any errors I can only speculate from here on out.

Comment: so here the lis to the code
teste.php(index) - http://pastebin.com/UpnzGSMr
testalerta.php - http://pastebin.com/RqxNtn1L
fancybox.js - http://pastebin.com/z3RAdWFM

thanks for the patience

Comment: Apologies, I am not able to access pastebin from my current location.

Comment: No problem. here it is on paste2
teste.php(index) - http://paste2.org/ZHDCb6sC
testalerta.php - http://paste2.org/FCUpdJmV
fancybox.js - http://paste2.org/KjW43Jzj

Comment: From what I can see there you create `auto_refresh()` but you never invoke it.

Comment: i have this _setInterval(function(),5000);_ with the function already inside the function _setInterval_

Comment: Ah - I see that now. Are you intending to overwrite auto_refresh? You call it once and then call it again.

Comment: i have two intervals for different functions. one of the function works, but the fancybox one, does not. I liked to be this way, with two interval for different functions if it is possible. i cant see how your solutions doesn't work such as the @JFK one...

Comment: when you declare auto_refresh the second time you're overwriting the one that you declare the first time. Name the second one something different.

Comment: I don't named the functions, could that be the problem?

Comment: honestly your code is really convoluted. You call fancybox numerous time, variables are overwriting variables. You should just create one file where you call your JavaScript code and include that code on every page within your site where the code will be used.

Comment: i commented all the code, less the function that we are dealing in this topic and still doesn't work

Comment: the sintax is correct and the browser does not report any errors

Comment: At this point, without major restructuring of your code and markup, I don't know what we can do. I have no place that I can run your code and it would be time consuming to cover all of the changes to make this work correctly while using current best practices for code organization.

Comment: I guess the problem now is not the organization because now i only have 7 lines of code. thanks for the pacience and the time. i will try to do other method

Answer (score 0):

Moving the script into index.php, I would do something like this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var myRefresh;
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    myRefresh = setInterval(function(){
    <?php
    $lines = file('alerta.txt');
    $valrec= $lines[0];
    echo $valrec; // do you need this echo ?
    if($valrec == 1){
    ?>
        $.fancybox({
            href: "alert.php",
            type: "iframe"
        });
    <?php  } else {  ?>
        clearInterval(myRefresh); // cancel interval if $valrec != 1
    <?php
    }; // closes if else (php)
    ?>
    },5000); // setInterval
}); //ready
</script>
```

Comment: no, i dont need the echo, it was just for test. i will test your code to see if it works. Thanks

Comment: it doesn't work. not even the echo that i use to test. the echo only works if it is out of the javascript. that means the page can find the file and read it, so that's not the problem.
here is the code of the all page - http://pastebin.com/ZmpmbbdF
the part that doesn't work is indicated

thanks for the help